# Populating User Control Property from Database Design Time

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, properties, user-controls

I am developing an application in C# using Windows Forms and a SQLite database.

A control I'm creating needs to retrieve data from the database so that it can populate the selectable options on a custom property. However, when I attempt to do this in code:

```
    public AddCategoryControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName == "devenv")
        {
            using (ResourceTypeRepository repo = new ResourceTypeRepository())
            {
                _resourceTypeList = repo.GetAllResourceTypes();
                if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(ResourceTypeList[0], null))
                {
                    ResourceType = ResourceTypeList[0];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And then I go to the Design Mode in Visual Studio, I receive this error: "No connection string named 'WinterContext' could be found in the application config file.

This doesn't make sense to me because when I actually run the application, it can find the database information just fine. For reference though, here is my App.Config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="WinterContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Data.Database.WinterEngineModel.csdl|res://*/Data.Database.WinterEngineModel.ssdl|res://*/Data.Database.WinterEngineModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SQLite;provider connection string='data source=&quot;C:\Users\Tyler\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WinterEngine\WinterEngineToolset\Data\WinterEngineDatabase.s3db&quot;'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I'm not sure what to do and my searches have come up with nothing. Hopefully one of you can assist.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't populate the control at design time as the code that makes the connection to the database isn't executed.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. So I guess there's really not a better option than to hard code the values? Assuming that it won't be able to read from an XML file either...

Comment: Not really. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm simply trying to make the options dynamic and to reduce the amount of code it takes to convert IDs to DTOs. But if it's not possible then I'll have to use another solution.